# Integration Laravel app with Google Ads Api

Tags: laravel, backend, google-ads-api

Has anyone created integrations with the Google Ads API? I specifically want to retrieve the number of searches based on the provided keywords. I know there are libraries to assist with integration, but they are stateful (at least the ones I found, and they don't work with Laravel 10). I've also found tutorials, such as https://www.bacancytechnology.com/blog/integrate-google-adwords-api-in-laravel-app, but they require grpc, and I've been informed by my hosting provider's support, where the project is hosted, that their hosting does not support grpc. The Google documentation itself is a bit peculiar. What is the simplest way to obtain this type of data? I should mention that this data must be obtained through the API, not, for example, through a CSV file. Do you have any ideas?